# Datatable linq select query

Tags: linq

I m trying to select a column's value from a datatable based on conditions.

```
var results = from DataRow myRow in dtCallBack.AsEnumerable()
              where myRow.Field<DateTime>(1) == startDateTime
                 && myRow.Field<int>(0) == callBackID
              select myRow.Field<int>(3);
```

My datatable contains 4 columns ID,Date1,Date2,IntVal

I want to convert the variable results to int. (I want to return the column 4 IntVal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var results = (from DataRow myRow in dtCallBack.AsEnumerable
              where myRow.Field<DateTime>(1) == startDateTime 
              && myRow.Field<int>(0) == callBackID
              select myRow.Field<int>(3)).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: `AsEnumerable` --> `AsEnumerable()`

Answer (score 1):

Well you've currently got an `IEnumerable<int>` by the looks of it. So which of those results do you want? What do you want to happen if there *aren't* any results?

If you're confident there's only a single result, you can use:

```
var result = results.Single();
```

If you want the first result or 0 if there aren't any, you could use

```
var result = results.FirstOrDefault();
```

If you want the first result and an exception if there aren't any, you could use

```
var result = results.First();
```

Basically there are lots of options, and you'll need to clarify your requirements before we can really give you a more concrete answer.

Comment: firstOrDefault would serve my purposeFirstOrDefault would do. If no results return 0.
startDateTime and callBackID are parameters to check.

Comment: @Premanshu: Unlike the accepted answer, I *wouldn't* call the variable `results` in the end then, given that you've only got a single result. I would personally probably separate it into the query and then the `SingleOrDefault` code for clarity - I generally dislike putting method calls at the end of query expressions.

Comment: @@Jon: My dataTable would have distinct set of callbackIDs and startDateTimes. I now prefer FirstOrDefault. The two columns may not be distinct individually though!!